# How to find and delete a specific record in table/grid using Selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

Assume that, a page contains a table of records (created dynamically) with Delete, Edit and View options (for each row/record). Now i want to find a specific record with name/id and delete that record. Is this possible in Selenium?

Help me to resolve this! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, we do this all the time in our tests.  You need to write an element locator that finds the row you want and identifies the appropriate button, then just `Selenium.Click(...)` on it.  The exact locator value will depend on your application, but it will probably be something like `xpath=//path/to/table/tr[td[pos() = 1 AND text() = 'My Name']]/td/button[@value='Delete']`.  In other words, "the button with the value 'Delete' in the row that has 'My Name' in its first cell in the table".

Comment: You're welcome.  FYI, the way you express thanks in StackOverflow is to mark the answer you liked best as "accepted".  That does a bunch of things, including giving the answering user some reputation points.